# What is the "en" in "Est-ce qu'il vaut mieux acheter un appartement ou en louer un?"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

The english meaning is "Is it better to buy an aparment or to rent one?". But literally, every words in English can be found in French, which makes "en" redundant, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike *one* in English, *un* cannot be used alone here.

*En* is a pronoun that refer to *appartement* :

> *...ou **en** louer un.* (or rent one of them)

means

> *...ou louer un **appartement**.*

Similarly, we can't say:

> *<s>Je veux un.</s>*  (I want one)

but we say instead:

> *J'en veux un.*

Comment: Or rather refers to *des appartements* since *en* always replaces a phrase headed by *de*